# static Factory method setting private variable when instationating Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, factory

I've noticed it's possible to do the following:

```
private int mSomeValue;
public static MyFragment newInstance(int someValue){
    MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
    myFragment.mSomeValue = someValue;
    myFragment.doSth();
    return myFragment;
}
private void doSth(){
    //do sth
}
```

My question is as follows- is this an acceptable way to e.g. set values or listeners or any other initial statet of a custom `Fragment` instance? Or should I always use `setArguments` in order to pass any values on creation time ?

Comment: I would stick with setArguments

Answer (score 1):

From [this page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html):

> All subclasses of Fragment must include a public no-argument constructor. The framework will often re-instantiate a fragment class when needed, in particular during state restore, and needs to be able to find this constructor to instantiate it. If the no-argument constructor is not available, a runtime exception will occur in some cases during state restore.

This basically means that sometimes the system will destroy your instance and remake it later (something you can't control!). Because of this you must stick to the following conventions.

The New Fragment wizard in Android Studio creates a good example of two things. I'll past the code in then describe it.

```
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public static BlankFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        BlankFragment fragment = new BlankFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public BlankFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        try {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }

        mListener.fragmentAttached(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        mListener.fragmentDetached(this);
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        public void fragmentAttached(BlankFragment fragment);
        public void fragmentDetached(BlankFragment fragment);
    }

}
```

Firstly, to create a new instance of this fragment, you use the static newInstance method, you can retrieve these arguments at any point using the getArguments() method. This example shows you how to do it in the onCreate() callback.

Secondly, this fragment requires that the hosting activity implements an interface. This example gives that activity a chance to add any listeners or whatever it wants to the fragment as soon as it's attached, and to dispose of them when the fragment is detached.

Comment: Yeah, that's how I've been doing it for years, but at some point noticed that you also can set e.g. the way i showed without actually overriding or passing any arguments to the constructor. Just wondering why this is not a valid way to do things. I've investigated `setArguments` method and it does basicly the same thing (or not?) it sets a private `mBundle` of the fragment.

Comment: Because it only affects that single instance - you'll get a different instance of that fragment if you, for example, rotate your device.

Comment: OK. That's the answer I was looking for! Thank you !

Comment: @aldorain: when android destroys and recreates the fragment, the fragment will loose the "mSomeValue" value. With joe-s solution the bundle still exists on recreating the fragment. the fragment can get "mSomeValue" (or ARG_PARAM1) again when being recreated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you always have to use `setArguments` for passing parameters to the fragment on creation time.

> Every fragment must have an empty constructor, so it can be
>   instantiated when restoring its activity's state. It is strongly
>   recommended that subclasses do not have other constructors with
>   parameters, since these constructors will not be called when the
>   fragment is re-instantiated; instead, arguments can be supplied by the
>   caller with setArguments(Bundle) and later retrieved by the Fragment
>   with getArguments().
>   http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html

Comment: Yes. but in the example I gave i'm not actually overriding a default constructor (or am I ?) hence I'm not really overstepping the guidelines.

Comment: You cannot be sure that the value stored in static variable will be the same after Android destroy and recreate the fragment.

Comment: Sure, I agree, but please note `mSomeValue` does not have to be static and is not called as such in the example I gave.

Comment: The point is you're setting variables and invoking methods on that particular instance of the fragment -- that instance might be destroyed and a different new one be used in the future. Because the new instance wasn't created in the same way, that stuff never happened to the new instance.